# Объединение строк в mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с сообщениями пользователей. user_id | message. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать объединение строк - выбрать все строки одного user_id, объединить поле message, создать одну новую строку, а старые удалить? Пытался с GROUP_CONCAT сделать, но не получается.

Comment: Что значит "объединить поле message"? А главное, зачем?

Comment: конкатенация типа

Comment: Использоваться потом эти сообщения по отдельности будут? Или нет? Почему у пользователя будет всего одно сообщение? Так и задумано?

Comment: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`message` SEPARATOR ', ') FROM `table` WHERE user_id=xxx

Comment: только ещё создать новую строку и удалить старые.

Comment: Как зачем?)) для оптимизации. То скрипт по одной строке дёргает 10 сообщений от гиперактивного юзера, а то бд их объединит и вместо 10 - будет одна :)

Comment: Логика скрипта сложная, поэтому я решил её не менять, а решить проблему средствами бд.

Comment: То есть Вы решили - хрен с им, пусть модель БД не соответствует процессу, зато мне не надо со скриптом возюкаться? Очень порочный подход. Граблеобильный...

Comment: Ну, если связь односторонняя, то почему бы и нет. Вот только почему тогда эти сообщения изначально не дописываются к оригинальному?

Comment: какому процессу? скрипт работает так - берёт строку, обрабатывает, помечает обработанной. берёт следующую и всё по новой. Гиперактивные юзеры пишут по 10 сообщений и 10 итераций тратится на одного юзера, а стальные ждут. А если бы объединить, то он его бы обработал за один подход.

Comment: Я думал дописывать, но в этот момент скрипт может обрабатывать эту запись. так как он запускается демоном, и запись и обработка - два разных процесса. Самый эффективный метод -- объединять записи перед выполнением, создавать новую, удалять старые

Comment: И что, скрипт 10 "строк" по одной обрабатывает дольше, чем одну десятикратной длины? и время обработки записи таково, что юзер ещё до завершения обработки успевает настучать ещё одну? Думаю, Вы не там ищете узкое место...

Comment: да, 10 записей больше чем одна :)

Comment: @Akina я понимаю что хрень, но там такой спагетти-код - я боюсь влезать в него)))  На данном этапе проще средствами бд. Перед обработкой выбрать, объединить, создать удалить.

Comment: скрипту, бд и серверу - пофигу на оптимизацию)) vk api отключается периодически из-за большого количества обращений

Comment: Ладно, сейчас на похапе конкатенирующий велосипед напишу, что делать?)) полдня с запросами провозился, так и не получилось ничего